# Having Trouble in creating Mongoose Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here im facing some proble while creating database.Im getting message mongo connected in console but my database isnt created even i have made the collection/model here is my code

ENV FILE

```
ATLAS_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ecommerce
```

Main.js File

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const routes = require("./Routes/routes")

const app = express();
const port = 5000 || process.env.port

// Controllers
const categoryController = require("./Controllers/category")
const feedbackController = require("./Controllers/feedback")
const productController = require("./Controllers/product")
const productRecieptController = require("./Controllers/productReciept")
const productReturnController = require("./Controllers/productReturn")
const userController = require("./Controllers/user")


const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI
mongoose.connect(uri,{useNewUrlParser:true,useCreateIndex:true,useUnifiedTopology: true})

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open",()=>{
    console.log('Database Server Connected');
})

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

 app.use("/categories",categoryController);
 app.use("/feedbacks",feedbackController);
 app.use("/products",productController);
app.use("/reciepts",productRecieptController);
app.use("/returns",productReturnController);
app.use("/users",userController);

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('App is running on Port 5000');
})
```

Product Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Category = require("./category")

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = new Schema({
    name:{type:String,required:true},
    totalQuantity:{type:Number,required:true},
    EcommerceQuantity:{type:Number,required:true},
    Category:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category',required:true},
    defaultPrice:{type:Number,required:true},
    discountPrice:{type:Number,required:true},
    Image:{type:String},
    Description:{type:String},
    Feedback:{type:Array},
    Availability:{type:Boolean},
})

const Product = mongoose.model("Product",productSchema)
module.exports = Product
```

Product Controller

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Product = require("../models/product")
const routes = require("../Routes/routes")

router.route(routes.GET_ALL_PRODUCTS).get((req,res)=>{
    Product.find()
    .then(products => res.json(products))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error : ",err))
})

router.route(routes.GET_PRODUCT).get((req,res)=>{
    Product.findById()
    .then(product => res.json(product))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error : ",err))
})

router.route(routes.DELETE_PRODUCT).delete((req,res)=>{
    Product.findByIdAndDelete()
    .then(() => res.json("Product Deleted Successfully"))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error : ",err))
})

module.exports = router
```

User Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name:{type:String,required:true},
    email:{type:String,required:true},
    password:{type:String,required:true},
    Country:{type:String,required:true},
    City:{type:String,required:true},
    hasDiscountedPrice:{type:Boolean,required:true},
    Address:{type:String,require:true},
    Phone:{type:String,require:true},
    facebook_id:{type:String},
    google_id:{type:String},
    type:{type:String,required:true}
})

const User = mongoose.model("User",userSchema)
module.exports = User
```

User Controller

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/user")
const routes = require("../Routes/routes")

router.route(routes.GET_ALL_USERS).get((req,res)=>{
    User.find()
  .then(users => res.status(200).json(users))
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error : ",err))
})

router.route(routes.GET_USER).get((req,res)=>{
   User.findById()
  .then(user => res.status(200).json(user))
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error : ",err))
})

router.route(routes.DELETE_USER).delete((req,res)=>{
    User.findByIdAndDelete()
   .then(() => res.status(200).json("User Deleted Successfully"))
   .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error : ",err))
 })

 module.exports = router
```

Routes File

```
const routes = {
    // Categories
    ADD_CATEGORY:'/add',
    GET_ALL_CATEGORIES:'/',
    GET_CATEGORY:'/:id',

    // Contact-US
    CONTACT_US:'contact-us',

    // Products 
    ADD_PRODUCT:'/add',
    GET_PRODUCT:'/:id',
    GET_ALL_PRODUCTS:'/',
    UPDATE_PRODUCT:'/:id',
    DELETE_PRODUCT:'/:id',

    // Product Reciept
    ADD_PRODUCT_RECIEPT:'/add',
    GET_PRODUCT_RECIEPTS:'/',
    GET_PRODUCT_RECIEPT:'/:id',

    // Product Return
    ADD_PRODUCT_RETURN:'/add',
    GET_PRODUCT_RETURNS:'/',
    GET_PRODUCT_RETURN:'/:id',

    // Users
    REGISTER_USER:"/register",
    LOGIN_USER:'/login',
    GET_ALL_USERS:'/',
    DELETE_USER:"/:id",
    UPDATE_USER:"/:id",
    GET_USER:"/:id",

    // Feedbacks
    ADD_USER_FEEDBACK:"/add",
    GET_ALL_FEEDBACK:"/",
    UPDATE_FEEDBACK:"/:id",
    DELETE_FEEDBACK:"/:id",
}

module.exports = routes
```

The other models are also with similar pattern can u tell me why my database is not being created

Comment: Did you insert any documents in any of the collections?

Comment: What do u mean by other documents i have just created the schema and created the model only in each file

Comment: MongoDB doesn't actually create any databases or collections until you insert a document or create an index.